# nginx is still showing splash page after configuration

Tags: nginx

I have a website, `mywebsite.io`

And this file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mywebsite.io.conf`

```
server { 
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     mywebsite.io;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        }
}
```

But when I visit my site I see the nginx splash page. Any clue why? From what I have seen online this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the default.conf from the conf.d dir? Because this contains the default server - also listening on port 80.

If you access your website using the server_name that you have specified it should work fine, but if you are just sending a get to port 80 you could see the default.

Comment: When I remove it I get 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: If I mess around some more I get failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Comment: ok, it sounds like your new config is not recognised. Can you create a SSH session on the nginx instance and run `nginx -T ` to show the full config and verify that all expected server/location blocks are present.